# Remapping Excel links VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a file with ~ 3000 links to other files. This file along with the linked files are being moved to a new location.

When I moved the files and the excel file, the path automatically got updated, however a new folder was introduced, and this folder was not added in the hyperlinks of excel.

Example:

```
Excel link: folder1/folder2/folder3/file.txt
Actual path: folder1/EXTRA_FOLDER/folder2/folder3/file.txt
```

How would I go about adding that one hyperlink in? Using VBA, how would I access hyperlinks?

Comment: What kind of hyperlinks?  `Insert>>Hyperlink` or `=HYPERLINK()` ?

Answer (score 5):

You could just replace the folder path in the address for all hyperlinks

```
Sub FixHyperLinks()
    Dim hLink As Hyperlink

    For Each hLink In Me.Hyperlinks
        hLink.Address = Replace(hLink.Address, "folder1/", "folder1/EXTRA_FOLDER/")
    Next

End Sub
```